# Maintaining ID value across multiple data steps

Tags: sas

I have a lot of different data sets that I have created, but I need to create a variable, ID, that will increase by 1 in the first data set for each row. In the next data set, I need to have the ID variable continue from where the last data step's ID variable left off.

I've tried using macro variables and retain statements but it's not working. The data sets that I'm using will change, so I can't just manually go in and set the second data set at the number #40 where the other left off. Here's an example of what I've done so far:

```
%let test_id=1;

data work.ex1;
    set work.ex1_test;
    ID + &test_id.;
    retain ID 0;
    call symput('test_id', &test_id.+1);
    first_name= First;
run;

data work.ex2;
    set work.ex2_test;
    ID + &test_id.;
    retain ID length(&test_id.);
    call symput('test_id', &test_id.+1);
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but not quite there.

You need to initialize `ID` to the macro variable.  Then increment it.  Then set the macro variable to the new value of `ID`.

```
%let initial_id=0;

data work.ex1;
    set sashelp.class;
    retain ID &initial_id.;
    ID+1;
    call symputx('initial_id', ID);
    first_name= name;
run;

data work.ex2;
    set sashelp.class;
    retain ID &initial_id.;
    ID+1;
    call symputx('initial_id',ID);
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

First i think it becomes wrong when you use: `ID + &test_id;` and then reset ID with the statement: `retain ID 0;`

Maybe this will work instead. Use the end= option in the set statement:

```
work.ex1 end=final;
```

Then add at the bottom of the code of the data step:

```
If final then do ;
id_next=id+1;
call symput('test_id',id_next);
end;
drop id_next;
```

Then start where you left off in the next data step using:

```
retain id &test_id ;
```

Comment: `retain ID 0` does not re-set the ID.  Retain is not an executable statement, so the `0` just initializes it at compile time; it's roughly equivalent to `if _n_=1 then ID=0;` except it occurs even before the `set` is processed (though it's also irrelevant if `ID` is on the set statement).

Comment: Otherwise I like some of the concept here.  While the approach I (and the OP) used is simpler and shorter, this approach is nice because it makes clear what happens at the end of the data step and thus is nicer from an organizational standpoint.  If the data step is doing a lot of different things, this approach is clearer and thus better.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the retain statement. Was unsure about it.

Comment: This is also better from a performance point of view - with very large datasets, doing a `call symput` for every row rather than just the last one can cause a noticeable impact.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose. What is your purpose of doing all that? what is your purpose to create an ID variable? if the sole purpose of ID is to identify the source of your final outcome by addressing the source table name, then SAS has built-in feature you may be able to leverage. The following code is example of using data step option 'INDSNAME='. First section is just to make up some sample tables, the second is to use this option to identify obs' wherefrom. It is rather straightward, so I haven't done in-line comments.

```
data class1 class2 class3;
    set sashelp.class;

    if age >14 then
        output class1;

    if sex='M' then
        output class2;
    else output class3;
run;

data test;
    set class: indsname=dsn;
    dsname=dsn;
run;
```

Comment: It's not super clear from the original question (though I edited it a bit ago to try and make it clearer) but I think the user wants ID value for each row, not for each table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dataset to store the last id used instead of a macro variable. If you make this a permanent dataset then it will work across sessions.

```
data lastid ;
  id=0;
run;

data a b ;
  do x=1 to 5; output; end;
run;

data new_a lastid (keep=id);
   if _n_=1 then set lastid ;
   if eof then output lastid ;
   set A end=EOF ;
   ID + 1 ;
   output new_a;
run;

data new_b lastid (keep=id);
   if _n_=1 then set lastid ;
   if eof then output lastid ;
   set b end=EOF ;
   ID + 1 ;
   output new_b;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

May be it's not the most elegant solution but one way could be:

1) Place a mark to each original data set, ie:

```
data work.ex1;
    set work.ex1;
    mark = 1;
run;

data work.ex2;
    set work.ex2;
    mark = 1;
run;
```

and so on...

2) Then append all the data sets togeher and create the id variable:

```
data work.all_sets;
    set work.ex1 work.ex2 ...;
    id = _n_;
run;
```

3) Last, separate the data sets again using the mark to know from which data set comes each row.

Comment: Can't say I understand what the purpose of `mark` is, the way you implemented it.  Did you mean `mark=2` in the second dataset? Either way, I don't see this as being an effective way to do it; it would be easier to obtain the rowcount value from the earlier dataset in another way rather than setting them together.

Comment: Yes, I meant mark=2. Still your solution is better.